# jQuery vertical tabs content starts after the tabs

Tags: jquery, css, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-community-builder

I'm building a website on Joomla and having a problem with my tabs on the profile page. Basically the content starts after the vertical tabs finish. You can see the screen shot attached.

What the problem would be? I've checked all html and css codes but couldn't find the problem.

Appreciate your help.!

[Vertical Tabs gap op top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKSCh.jpg)

Comment: can we see your code please?

Comment: Well I'm using an external component to be able to add jquery tabs to my community builder profile called community builder profile pro. They allow me to add tabs using {TAB}{/TAB} codes. I can't add my codes since I have character limits on this comment section.

Comment: Is there any other way to add my codes here? Sorry I'm new here.

Comment: [Fiddle it](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Here's my html codes http://jsfiddle.net/p5BsH/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem will be the `clear: both` I think as that means nothing can be floated to the left/right of the content. Try floating the tabs on the left and the content on the right. that should work!

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I've stayed up till morning and play with the css codes of the smoothness theme of the tabs. And end up adding float: inherit; to the .smoothness .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel section and it's all good now. Thank you very much for the idea of "floating" George.

Comment: Not at all! Glad you got it fixed!